# Session "NT Kernel Logger" failed to start

Tags: windows-server-2012, kernel, windows-event-log, session

I have encountered an error on windows server 2012 recently.

```
Session "NT Kernel Logger" failed to start with the following error: 0xc0000022
```

**More Details:**
LogName: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing/Admin
Event ID: 2
Level: error
OpCode: start

- What causes this error?
- Is this an important error or I can ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the Event properties details, you will find the associated ProcessID and ThreadID:

[image]

If the event is relatively current, the Process ID  should still be registered by the offending process. Open task manager and go to processes tab and list processes by PID.

Now you can find out which process causes this event.

for more info please refer to [this link](https://lokna.no/?p=2048)